# Saving data to access not working, despite no errors

Tags: vb.net

Hey I'm trying to use this code to save to my access database and although there are no errors and it says data saved, my access database doesn't receive the new data. What's wrong with it?

```
Private Sub savenew()
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn = New OleDbConnection
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbsource = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim command As OleDbCommand

        Try
            conn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "insert into item(name) values ('" & TextBox4.Text & "')"
            command = New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader
            MsgBox("data saved")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

(table in my database is called item, and column is called name.)

Comment: [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery) -- [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters).

Comment: Hey Jimi again! Where do I put each?

Comment: `Dim query As String = "insert into [item] ([name]) values (@NameValue)" command.Parameters.Add("@NameValue", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text command.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Both the Connection and the Command must be disposed or declared in a `Using` block. As a side note, both `item` and `name` are really bad choices as table/field names. You should rename them.

Comment: Jimi it worked thanks!!! I found out that somehow my datasource had to be hardcoded. Since your here would you know a filepath that would work for every computer, as mine only works with mine (my database is stored in the project file with the exe that runs the code.)

Comment: `Dim databasePath = Path.Combine(Application.StatupPath, "FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb"). Dim dbprovider as String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={databasePath};Persist Security Info=false;"`. Connections can also be store in a configuration file, but, with an Access DB file, this is good enough.

Comment: Thanks again Jimi you've really helped me with my project!!! Now this may be too much but my final goal is to allow users to create and save their own deck (through another table in the database) however: cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE values('" & TextBox4.Text & "') (ID COUNTER, [name] STRING)"

Comment: Whether you store the connection string in the config file or not, use "|DataDirectory|" for the folder path of data files, as shown [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/datadirectory-functionality/).

Comment: Please don't keep asking questions in the comments of unrelated questions. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Comment: yep, sorry no worries

Comment: If he's new he can't upvote you but we got your back :)